# BLOG system SQL summery query problems

Tags: mysql, sql, join, categories

Ok, I give up, this query is over my head, I am seeking help.

Inside a MySQL database, I have a category and a post table, just like a standard blog system:

```
tblCategories (intID (PK), strTitle)
tblAreas (intID (PK), strName)
tblPosts (intID (PK), intCategoryID (FK), strTitle, htmlText)
```

Then I have a couple of blog supporting tables:

```
tblExternalLinks (intID (PK), intPostID (FK), strTitle, urlLink)
tblComments (intID (PK), intPostID (FK), strComment)
tblImages (intID (PK), intPostID (FK), urlImage)
tblLocations (intID (PK), intPostID (FK), intAreaID (FK), urlImage)
```

1. I want a list of all Posts that are attached to a category variable
   (let's just say in pseudo php code) $intCatID, AND that has a
   location with a certain area variable $intAreaID. This SQL should be
   something like:

   ```
   SELECT tblPosts.* from tblPosts 
   INNER JOIN tblLocations ON tblLocations.intPostID=tblPosts.intID 
   WHERE intCategoryID=$intCatID AND intAreaID=$intAreaID GROUP BY tblPosts.intID;
   ```

   Can someone please let me know if this is correct? I'm not sure bout
   the GROUP BY part.
2. I want the same list, but this time with Counts of all the other
   attached records in the supporting tables:

   ```
   SELECT tblPosts.*, intExternalLinksCount, intCommentsCount, intImagesCount, intLocationsCount ...
   ```

   My first guess is retrieving the counts using nested tables, or
   joins, which probably will make the query very large. I also wonder
   what is faster for performance. These things are where I bang my
   head.

And answers are highly appreciated...

Comment: GROUP BY is for use in conjunction with aggregating functions. These functions are normally included within the SELECT clause, although this is not a requirement. As a rule, any non-aggregated column appearing in the SELECT clause MUST be included in the GROUP BY clause. In a deviation from the standard, MySQL forgives this omission. It just means you end up with unpredictable results.

Comment: Consider providing a small, but representative data set (as an SQLFIDDLE and/or 'DDLs'), together with the result set you'd expect from your query.

Comment: No, because then I would be asking an exact query solution, whereas I want a pseudo-query that I understand (and build the query myself). The perfect answer would be a query with the right structures, where the solution is visible within it, but not necessarily working. Also, the above table & field names have been changed to protect the business trade knowledge (of course). An exact query would therefore not be a solution anyway. I think the problem is clear enough...

Comment: So i guess some answers are more appreciated than others ;-)

Answer (score 0):

And just because I would love to receive critical feedback, I came up with this (very, very ugly) query:

```
SELECT 
tblPosts.*, 
tblTempLocations.intLocationsCount, 
tblTempLinks.intLinksCount, 
tblTempImages.intImagesCount, 
tblTempComments.intCommentsCount,
tblTempNearest.fltNearestLocationAngle
FROM tblAdverts 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT intPostID, count(*) as intLocationsCount 
  FROM tblLocations 
  GROUP BY intPostID)
 tblTempLocations ON tblPosts.intID=tblTempLocations.intPostID
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT intPostID, count(*) as intLinksCount 
  FROM tblLinks 
  GROUP BY intPostID)
 tblTempLinks ON tblPosts.intID=tblTempLinks.intPostID
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT intPostID, count(*) as intImagesCount
  FROM tblImages
  GROUP BY intPostID)
 tblTempImages ON tblPosts.intID=tblTempImages.intPostID
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT intPostID, count(*) as intReviewsCount 
  FROM tblComments
  GROUP BY intPostID)
 tblTempComments ON tblPosts.intID=tblTempComments.intPostID
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT intPostID, 
  MIN(SQRT(POWER((fltLatitude - $fltCurrentLatitude), 2) + POWER((fltLongitude - $fltCurrentLongitude),2))) AS fltNearestLocationAngle 
  FROM tblLocations 
  GROUP BY intPostID) 
 tblTempNearest ON tblPosts.intID=tblTempNearest.intPostID
INNER JOIN tblLocations ON tblPosts.intID=tblLocations.intPostID
WHERE tblLocations.intLocationID=$intAreaID  AND tblPosts.strTitle LIKE '%$strPartialTitle%' AND tblAdverts.intCategoryID=$intCatID
GROUP BY tblAdverts.intID
```